# Array formatting help needed?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have two arrays. Now i want to compare some elements in from both arrays based on that i need to populate one array element to the new array.

```
 Array1: $days this is an array of elements between two dates.

$days = Array
       (
         [0] => 2012-06-23
         [1] => 2012-06-24
         [2] => 2012-06-25
         [3] => 2012-06-26
         [4] => 2012-06-27
         [5] => 2012-06-28
         [6] => 2012-06-29
         [7] => 2012-06-30
         [8] => 2012-07-01
         [9] => 2012-07-02
         [10] => 2012-07-03
         [11] => 2012-07-04
         [12] => 2012-07-05
         [13] => 2012-07-06
         [14] => 2012-07-07
         [15] => 2012-07-08
         [16] => 2012-07-09
         [17] => 2012-07-10
         [18] => 2012-07-11
         [19] => 2012-07-12
         [20] => 2012-07-13
         [21] => 2012-07-14
         [22] => 2012-07-15
         [23] => 2012-07-16
        )

 Array2: $summary is the array which i am getting from the database..

 $summary = Array
 (
    [0] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2012-06-23 
        [no_of_posts] => 1
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2012-06-24 
        [no_of_posts] => 2
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2012-06-25 
        [no_of_posts] => 1
    )

    [3] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2012-06-26 
        [no_of_posts] => 1
    )

    [4] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2012-06-27
        [no_of_posts] => 1
    )
```

Now from these both arrays i need an array which tells me on this date this many times posts are there if there no posts against one date then it should be zero for that. I tried like this.....

```
    $result = array();
   foreach($summary as $key=>$s) {
       foreach($days as $d) {
          if($s['date'] == $d) {
               $result[$d] = $s['no_of_posts'];
          } else {
               $result[$d] = 0;
          }
      }
   }
```

I know there is mistake i can't able to find...........any ideas.

Output array need to look like below.....

```
    $result = Array
            Array
       (
         [2012-06-23] = 1
         [2012-06-24] = 2
         [2012-06-25] = 1
         [2012-06-26] = 1
         [2012-06-27] = 1
         [2012-06-28] = 0
         [2012-06-29] = 0
         [2012-06-30] = 0
         [2012-07-01] = 0
         [2012-07-02] = 0
         [2012-07-03] = 0
         [2012-07-04] = 0
         [2012-07-05] = 0
         [2012-07-06] = 0
         [2012-07-07] = 0
         [2012-07-08] = 0
         [2012-07-09] = 0
         [2012-07-10] = 0
         [2012-07-11] = 0
         [2012-07-12] = 0 
         [2012-07-13] = 0
         [2012-07-14] = 0
         [2012-07-15] = 0
         [2012-07-16] = 0
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest way is to loop through your database results and create a values array indexed by date:

```
$summaryTotals = array();
foreach($summary as $dbSummary) {
    $summaryTotals[$dbSummary['date']] = $dbSummary['no_of_posts'];
}
```

Then iterate through your dates array inputting the values where a match occurs in the summary array, like so:

```
$dayValues = array();
foreach($days as $day) {
    if(isset($summaryTotals[$day])) {
        $dayValues[$day] = $summaryTotals[$day];
    } else {
        $dayValues[$day] = 0;
    }
}
```

The dayValues array should now be what you're after. I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
   $newArr = array();

    foreach($summary as $key=>$s) {
      $newArr[$s['date']] = $s['no_of_posts'];
    }

    $newDays = array_fill_keys(array_values($days),'0');

    $newData = $newDays + $newArr;

    print_r ($newData);
```

Comment: I believe this route may lose his key ordering because of the final array merge, which is why I did the double loop. Nice readability though.

Answer (score -1):

The code should be:
$days = array
        (
            0 => '2012-06-23',
            1 => '2012-06-24',
            2=> '2012-06-25',
            3=> '2012-06-26',
            4=> '2012-06-27',
            5=> '2012-06-28',
            6=> '2012-06-29',
            7=> '2012-06-30',
            8=> '2012-07-01',
            9=> '2012-07-02',
            10 => '2012-07-03',
            11 => '2012-07-04',
            12 => '2012-07-05',
            13 => '2012-07-06',
            14 => '2012-07-07',
            15 => '2012-07-08',
            16 => '2012-07-09',
            17 => '2012-07-10',
            18 => '2012-07-11',
            19 => '2012-07-12',
            20 => '2012-07-13',
            21 => '2012-07-14',
            22 => '2012-07-15',
            23 => '2012-07-16',
            );
        $summary = array
        (
            0 => array
            (
                'date' => '2012-06-23',
                'no_of_posts' => 1
                ),

```
        1 => array
        (
            'date' => '2012-06-24' ,
            'no_of_posts' => 2
            ),

        2 => array
        (
            'date' => '2012-06-25', 
            'no_of_posts' => 1
            ),

        3 => array
        (
            'date' => '2012-06-26' ,
            'no_of_posts' => 1
            ),

        4 => array
        (
            'date' => '2012-06-27',
            'no_of_posts' => 1
            )
        );

    $result = array();
    foreach($summary as $key=>$s) {
        foreach($days as $d) {
            if($s['date'] == $d) {
                $result[$d] = $s['no_of_posts'];
            } else if(!isset($result[$d])){
                $result[$d] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```